# Character € is not working with sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus

I'm having a problem with my database with the character €.
With the Oracle SQL Developer it works fine. But if I try to query using putty and sqlplus, the character € is not recognized.

It's shows next results:

```
SQL> select column from table;

column
------------------------------------
10▒
------------------------------------
It should be 10€
```

And if try with a SELECT with a WHERE like:

```
SQL> select column from table where column like '%€%';

no rows selected
```

Both SELECT in SQL Developer shows the right answer.

Here is the config of the data base:

```
    PARAMETER               VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE            SPANISH                
NLS_TERRITORY           SPAIN                  
NLS_CURRENCY            €                      

NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        SPAIN                  
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  ,.                     
NLS_CALENDAR            GREGORIAN              

NLS_DATE_FORMAT         DD/MM/RR               
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       SPANISH                
NLS_CHARACTERSET        WE8MSWIN1252           

NLS_SORT                SPANISH                
NLS_TIME_FORMAT         HH24:MI:SSXFF          
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF 

NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR      
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR                                      

NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       €                      

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16              
NLS_COMP                BINARY                 
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE                   

NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     FALSE
```

And here is the config of the server:

```
> locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

> echo $NLS_LANG
AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
```

Comment: Maybe related: [€ Euro sign/symbol not showing up on Oracle 10gr2 and aix 6.1](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20016).

Comment: Is it stored as varchar2 or nvarchar2; and can you query `dump(column, 16)` and `dump('€', 16)` to compare them? Is SQL Developer configured for Win1252 or UTF? (I suspect the wrong code point is recorded for the character set, but mostly guessing...). I don't think it's the problem in the linked answer as your DB character set should support the symbol - but you may be looking for the wrong codepoint, perhaps.

Comment: It's stored as  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR).

Comment: If I run that queries I obtain next result: select dump('€',16) from dual;

DUMP('�▒',16)
----------------------
Typ=96 Len=3: e2,82,ac

Comment: @KikeAcedoDorado - right, which is the [UTF-8 codepoint for the euro symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/charset_support.htm). You see that in a session with the WIN1252 NLS_LANG? I would have expected that to have had to be UTF-8 for some reason. Anyway, what do you get when you dump the actual column value? I suspect that will be different. And which terminal are you using, and what translation is that (also WIN1252, or UTF8, or 8859-1, or something else) - which might affect the actual display?

Comment: I see that in a session with NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: The dump for the column value was: DUMP(COLUMN:,16)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=1: 80

Comment: I think that the system is converting the € system from 80 to e2,82,ac, isn't it?

Comment: I'm doing that from putty, the database server is AIX and translation from putty is:WIN1252

Comment: A more useful test would be doing both of the dumps with second argument 1016 instead of 16, sorry. The data store in the column and the string literal you are using to search are different code points, so as far as Oracle is concerned they don't match; and PuTTY is having trouble displaying the generated character - which is a separate issue really (but you can set the translation to UTF-8). I can't test this, but does `select column from table where column like '%'|| utl_i18n.raw_to_char(utl_i18n.string_to_raw('€', 'WE8MSWIN1252'))|| '%'` find the row?

Comment: And/or, does your original query work if you do `export LANG=es_ES@euro"` first, if that is shown by `locale -a`? It might have knock-on effects on other things that expect UTF-8 but would be interesting to know anyway. I suspect it wont' make any difference, but you never know...

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole! It has been solved. The problem was the putty configuration. Putty sucks and if you change the character set and don't save, the chages are missed. Thanks again @AlexPoole

Comment: This isn't a forum; rather than modifying your question to show the fix (and changing the title to 'solved'), you should post an answer that explains how you fixed it, so a future visitor with the same issue can find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This is solved. There was putty configuration problem.

Solution:

Change character set on putty translation tab to: Win 1252 (Western).

[image: Putty screenshot]